# Implementing and understanding a Blazor Static Server-Side Rendered Counter Page

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

Blazor Web App Template, selecting 'None' for the Interactive Render mode.

To begin my understanding of Static Server-Side Rendering (SSR), as it is implemented in Blazor compared to that of MVC or Razor pages, I thought I might implement the missing Counter component, similar to the interactive versions of the template.

This code seems to work fine, without query string params, cookies or JS interop for using browser storage (all approaches I considered)...

```
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter - BlazorSSR</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @CurrentCount</p>

<EditForm Enhance FormName="counterForm" Model="CurrentCount" OnSubmit="IncrementCount">
    <InputNumber class="d-none" @bind-Value="CurrentCount" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Click me</button>
</EditForm>

@* Thanks to Ruikai Feng's answer, this is interchangeable with the above EditForm:
<form data-enhance method="post" @formname="counterForm" @onsubmit="IncrementCount">
    <AntiforgeryToken />
    <input type="number" @bind-value="@CurrentCount" name="CurrentCount" hidden />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Click me</button>
</form>
*@

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public int CurrentCount { get; set; }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        CurrentCount += 1;
    }
}
```

My questions:

1. Why does this work?
   It appears to me the IncrementCount() method is running per the OnSubmit, and the resulting form-submission is being supplied as a parameter back to the same page, successfully incrementing the CurrentCount.  Is that correct?
2. Is this the correct and simplest approach for implementing the Counter page?  Just because it works, doesn't mean it's correct.
3. For the InputNumber, I would have preferred a standard HTML input with type="hidden", but  couldn't find the correct way to bind the CurrentCount.  I realize I'm not using a traditional 'model' here, and I'm just using a native int.  Seemed silly to create an entire model just for a single int.
4. Having the understanding of MVC, with POST-Redirect-Get, what's the workflow here?  I'm not injecting the NavigationManager, so after the OnSubmit runs IncrementCount(), is it just reloading the same page, and somehow taking the CurrentCount from my form submission and feeding it back into itself?
5. So what's the pattern here?  If I redirected to another page, can I pass the form submission data into the other page, or do I have to stay on the current page, do something with the data, and then redirect to another page?
6. Because this is SSR, I expect, in terms of DI, that Scoped and Transient mean the same thing.  So had I injected a service to keep track of the CurrentCount, only a Singleton would work, at the expense of the Counter value being the same for everyone.

### Update:

While Ruikai Feng's answer is helpful, I need to address my fundamental misunderstanding for the Blazor SSR form submission workflow, as with static server-side rendering, the workflow is quite different compared with a page having interactivity.

To that end, I created a page slightly more complex than the Counter page, albeit a simple example to demonstrate the workflow.

```
@page "/FormLifecycle"

<PageTitle>Form Lifecycle - BlazorSSR</PageTitle>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 mx-auto">
        <h1>Form Lifecycle Testing</h1>
        
        <EditForm class="mb-2" Enhance Model="Person" FormName="personForm" OnValidSubmit="SubmitPerson">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <span class="input-group-text" for="firstName">First Name</span>
                <InputText id="firstName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="Person.FirstName" />
            </div>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Person.FirstName)" class="mb-3 text-danger" style="margin-top: -16px;" />

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <span class="input-group-text" for="lastName">Last Name</span>
                <InputText id="lastName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="Person.LastName" />
            </div>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Person.LastName)" class="mb-3 text-danger" style="margin-top: -16px;" />

            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </EditForm>
        
        @if (PersonModel.IsModelValid(Person, out _))
        {
            <p>Submitted: @Person.FirstName @Person.LastName</p>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "personForm")]
    public PersonModel Person { get; set; } = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnInitialized()");
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnParametersSet()");
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnAfterRender()");
    }

    private void SubmitPerson()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SubmitPerson()");

        if (PersonModel.IsModelValid(Person, out _))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Submitted: {Person.FirstName} {Person.LastName}");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:
OnInitialized()
OnParametersSet()
[I filled in the form and pressed submit]
OnInitialized()
OnParametersSet()
SubmitPerson()
Submitted: Homer Simpson

I expected the SubmitPerson() method to be run before reloading the page, not after.

Suppose I was displaying a list of people from a database on the same page as the form.  It seems to me, this would reload the same page over again, then submit the new person... leaving it to me to reload the page a third time, OR fake it by manually adding the submitted person to the list of people from the database, without actually reloading the page or reloading database results.

I may have answered my own question with this little experiment, just it feels the answer is not as intuitive as I would have thought.  My aim is to utilize static server-side rendering as much as possible, to avoid/minimize the need for web sockets or client-side activity, as much as possible.

Comment: Upon further debugging with a more complex example than Counter, it seems submitting the form first reloads the page, i.e. runs OnInitialized(), then runs the method specified in OnSubmit on the new/refreshed page.  So you have to think ahead, that submitting a form will reload the page and run OnInitialized() again.  This seems less than intuitive at the moment.  Hoping someone is able to make sense of this workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Blazor static server-side rendering, here is my rendition of the Counter page:

```
@page "/counter/{reset:bool?}"
@inject NavigationManager NavMan

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @CurrentCount</p>

<form class="d-inline" data-enhance method="post" @formname="counterForm" @onsubmit="IncrementCount">
    <AntiforgeryToken />
    <input type="number" @bind-value="@CurrentCount" name="CurrentCount" hidden />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Click me</button>
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/counter/true">Reset</a>
</form>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool Reset { get; set; }
    
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public int CurrentCount { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (Reset)
        {
            NavMan.NavigateTo("/counter");
        }
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        CurrentCount += 1;
    }
}
```

And answers to my own questions:

When you submit the form, the form data is loaded into the model annotated with `[SupplyParameterFromForm]`.

Note 1: In the counter example, there is only an int variable, not really a model, but the framework seems to handle this scenario, hence no `Model="modelName"` attribute is required on form tag. In your average scenario, there would be a Model attribute specified.

Note 2: If you have multiple forms on the page, thus multiple models, you should annotate each model `[SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "xyzForm")]`. Careful as SupplyParameterFromForm has a 'Name' property, which isn't the right one, it's 'FormName'.

So after pressing submit, presuming the form/EditForm passes validation, it will populate the form data into the model AND the page will reload with the OnInitialized/Async() method.

As remarked in the question, the flow is this:
OnInitialized
OnParametersSet
[User Submits form]
OnInitialized
OnParametersSet
Method specified in OnSubmit/OnValidSubmit attribute will run.

This means in OnInitialized(), you must look for and handle the scenario where your data model is already populated, i.e. take care not to re-initialize it.  This is where the null-coalescing operator is helpful [??=].

On the initial page load, your model might be null and perhaps you'll have to initialize it. But after a form submission, the model will be populated, so you shouldn't initialize it. You have to check this!

This can be observed in the examples from the Blazor documentation for .NET 8:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

As for the traditional MVC pattern of GET-POST-REDIRECT, it's simply a matter of, what do you want to do in the method specified in your OnSubmit/OnValidSubmit attribute?  Do you want to stay on the same page, or do you want to redirect somewhere else?

If you want to redirect somewhere else, inject the NavigationManager and use the NavigateTo() method.  This way, you can take action with the form submission model data, and then redirect somewhere else, if that is your requirement.

One last topic along the lines of redirecting.  Let's say you have a button on your form, or a link, which will redirect the user to another page.  If you don't need to take any action other than redirecting, you need not a form for this, you can just use an anchor tag, e.g. from the Counter page, the reset button:

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/counter/true">Reset</a>
```

And the `OnInitialized()` method of the Counter page will recognize when the Reset parameter is populated, and reload the page to effectively 'reset' the count.

If I had a scenario where I had multiple buttons that took different actions, and it was a static server-side rendered page, then I would need multiple forms, so the OnValidSubmit method could take those actions and decide what to do next.

Perhaps MVC seems more intuitive, purely because it was learned before Blazor, and the idea of a Controller vs a code-behind helps to think of server-side vs view concerns separately, but it is really a matter of orienting yourself to Blazor, when working purely in static SSR, that the code section is running server-side, and the markup is the client-side view.

Answer (score 1):

For Q1,Q2:

You could Press F12 and check NetWork in your browser,you are sending http request to server instead of interacting with SignalR as usual :
[image]

[image]

For Q3,if you wish it work in SSR,you may try:

```
<input type="number" @bind-value="@CurrentCount" name="CurrentCount" hidden/>
```

For Q4:
There's no  `POST-Redirect-Get` here,it just send the rendered html codes back as the response of your post request

For Q5:
You could check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=server) related with Blazor state management

For Q6:
Scoped and Transient never mean the same thing,if you register a service as Scoped,it would keep the same instance per http request in asp.net core ,if you register it as Transient,once you inject them into different components/services,you would get different instance

Comment: My questions indeed have some overlap, and I've done some further debugging since asking the question.  Obviously I understand there's no POST-Redirect-Get here, but I've come to understand that a form submission using SSR-only seems to reload the same page, running OnInitialized() again, and then runs the method indicated by the OnSubmit from the form.  Is that observation correct?  This means (to me) that you must be careful in your OnIntialized() method, especially when you're trying to POST some update to your backend and update your frontend view.

Comment: You indeed answered my question regarding using a standard HTML form with an input, for which I've updated my question to include the alternative to the EditForm.  However, to me, the workflow described in my above comment is unclear in the Blazor documentation I've viewed thus far-- that submitting a form results in calling OnInitlized() over again.  Also, you're answer to Q6, I understand the difference in general, but require some context with Blazor SSR.  On an SSR page, there seems to be no difference between Scoped and Transient.